# Surge Protecter's Grounded Light Turning Off

Tags: power-supply, power, computer-building

I've got a new PC setup in a new apartment (built before 1980s), however the surge protector I have is doing some funny things. Any help would be appreciated.

- When I plug the surge protector into a 3-prong outlet, both the "Protected" and "Grounded" lights turn on.
- When I plug in the monitor's power cord into the surge protector, there are no changes.
- When I plug in the computer, the "Grounded" light turns off.
- If I unplug, or switch off the PSU, the computer, the "Grounded" light comes back on.

I've done some searching and found some other people asking about the grounding in buildings built before the 80s. Apparently, when converting 2-prong sockets into 3-prong sockets, the grounding might be overlooked.

But since I'm getting the "Grounded" light to turn on without the computer attached, I'm wondering if it's something specific with my surge protector or computer.

Surge Protector: RCA PS28210B
Computer: 750W power supply. Build should only be drawing about 400W

Thanks!

Comment: Try a new surge protector.

Comment: Typically it indicates a faulty or inadequate ground circuit. But it could be faulty surge protector too. An electrician can test the circuit to see if it is properly grounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lights are definitely reporting something that should not exist.  Apparently something is making the safety ground pretend to be good.  Then leakage from some connected device is increasing that voltage too much.

A human safety problem clearly exists.  To say more required numbers best obtained from a meter.   Trying a different protector is classic shotgunning.  Just keep replacing good parts until something works when no one has any idea how electricity works.

Your symptoms imply a human safety problem.  More than that cannot be stated without hard facts that any layman (with instructiions) can obtain.  Any answer without those facts is best ignored.

Second alternative is an electrician who will simply do the same layman simple meter readings to find the defect BEFORE fixing anything.

Comment: Thanks westom. I tried a different surge protector and this one never has the grounding light come on. Looks like there's no proper grounding in the outlets.